# Iptables or something to redirect IP in gateway (GNU/Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, redirect, iptables, quota

Im writing a bash scripting to account traffic in my network server:

WAN:eth1 -> GNU/Linux Server:eth0 -> Users
The GNU/Linux server uses squid, bind, QoS, mysql, lighttpd.

After an IP exceed the established quota a new QoS rule is applied for that IP (user) too exist one "flag" to decide when is restored the IP counter to Zero.

Some IPs and subnets work without quotas, other gruop of ips/subnets work with new QoS after quota is exceeded, and now I wanna work with a third group with redirection after quota is exceeded.

When an IP exceed the established quota all http traffic must be redirected to host (lighttpd runing on GNU/Linux ) and DROP all other traffic generated for that IP. In webserver exist a webpage with: "You exceed your daily quote of traffic, please wait "x" hours or call to your provider to purchase an extra navigation package" or something like that.

Is possible using a chain, or how can I do that?.
The most topics that I found in Internet, are related to block all and create a new chain to let out to Internet (not work for me). And other redirect only IP by IP, but how can I create something that a "chain" and attach the IPs to must me redirected to can after restore that IPs easly?

Thanks for help and sorry for my poor English :S.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. After apply that redirection, the IP must be restored (redirected to squid), how can restore that redirection and "delete" the web server redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.100.66 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -s 192.168.100.66 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth1 -d 192.168.100.66 -j DROP
```

This will redirect packets from 192.168.100.66 on port 80 to the local webserver on the loopback interface, allow that conversation, then reject all other packets being routed to 192.168.100.66 on the WAN interface.

To restore the connection back to normal you will want to delete those firewall entries:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -s 192.168.100.66 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
iptables -D INPUT -i lo -s 192.168.100.66 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D INPUT -i eth1 -d 192.168.100.66 -j DROP
```

Comment: Your third rule (OUPTUT -s 192.168.100.66 -j REJECT) is pointless (no effect), since the fw won't be outputting packets with src=100.66 in light of the scenario saying that dst=100.66.

Comment: Edited to drop packets destined to 100.66 on the WAN interface. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I thought that to restore the iptables to that client, was necesary delete all iptables related to that ip, and begin to recreate it adding iptables rules one by one. But now all is clear for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that iptables itself (well, the xtables-addons extension set providing *quota2*) can already do the quota matching magic and you can (re)set the values through procfs, combined with REDIRECT as @resmon6 says:

```
-t nat -s user1addr -m quota2 --name user1 ! --quota 0 -j REDIRECT...
-t nat -s user2addr -m quota2 --name user2 ! --quota 0 -j REDIRECT...
```

The syntax is a arguably a little odd right now (0 is the *initial value only* and is independent from the runtime quota *test* involving the negational `!`. Noticing this just now, a patch may make it in to unroll this confusing syntax in the future).